# sign extension to 16 bit

Tags: c

I convert an `int` number to binary but I need to sign extend to 16 bits f the binary is 011, i.e. I need to print it in `0000000000000011`.
I also have a problem in evaluating the binary of a negative number if it's greater than 7.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    int x;  
    char inst[4][15]={"addi","8"};

    int rem, num=0, i=1;
    int y;
    int num1 = atoi(inst[1]);
    if (num1 < 0) 
    {
        x=atoi(inst[1]);
        x = (x * -1) -1;            
        printf("x %d",x);
        while(x > 0)
        {
            rem = x % 2;
            x= x / 2;
            num = (rem * i)+num;
            i = i  * 10;
            y = num ^ 111;
        }
        printf("binary no: %d",y);
    }
    else 
    {
        x = atoi(inst[1]);
        while(x > 0)
        {         
            rem = x % 2;
            x = x / 2;
            num = (rem * i) + num;
            i = i * 10;
        }
        printf("binary no: %d", num);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what does the above code do?

Comment: @SherineShafei Your code has so much redundancy...

Comment: this code takes the int number inside the string convert to integer then to binary number i need to extend this binary number to 16 bit

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for 32bit integer.Will this give you a hint.

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <stdlib.h>
  3 
  4 int
  5 main(void)
  6 {
  7     const char set[] = {'0', '1'};
  8     int number;
  9     unsigned int unumber, tmp;
 10     int i, loop;
 11     char * output, * cpy;
 12 
 13 
 14     scanf("%d", &number);
 15     unumber = (unsigned int)number;
 16 
 17     loop = sizeof(unsigned int) * 8;
 18     output = malloc(loop + 1);
 19     cpy = output + loop;
 20     *cpy = '\0';
 21     cpy--;
 22 
 23     for(i = 0; i < loop; i++)
 24         *cpy-- = set[(unumber >> i & 1)];
 25 
 26 
 27     printf("%s\n", output);
 28     free(output);
 29 
 30     return 0;
 31 }
 32
```

example input and output:

```
10
00000000000000000000000000001010
-1
11111111111111111111111111111111
```